# How do I open a flatpak file on EOS 5.1.7?

Tags: flatpak

I have a file `Program.flatpak`.  I can't find any way to open it.

Every google search I've found merely states that Elementary OS has flatpak, but gives no details about how or where or what that means.

I tried typing `$ flatpak` into console, but it yields no results.

So I tried installing `$ sudo apt install flatpak` and it says nothing has been updated.

Apparently flatpak is here -- somewhere -- but how do I make it open a flatpak file?

Answer (score 0):

Found on [Reddit of all places](https://www.reddit.com/r/flatpak/comments/iigaym/how_can_i_install_or_run_a_flatpak_file/)

`$ flatpak install path/to/file`

I'm going to put in a feature request to have this be something EOS handles on its own.